How can I avoid Maximum stack depth has been reached on multi queueable single class?
I'm presenting the Maximum stack depth has been reached. error only on testing, how can avoid this error if I have created this nested queueable in just one class?
This is the class used.
global class ChainComposer {
global static String threadId;

public final String channelId;
public final String content;
public final String timestamp;
public final String threadTs;


global ChainComposer(String channel, String message, String ts, String threadTs) {
    this.channelId = channel;
    this.content = message;
    this.timestamp = ts;
    this.threadTs = threadTs;
}


global void doWork() {
    try {
        System.enqueueJob(new async1(channelId, content, timestamp, threadTs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
}

global class async1 implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private final String channelId;
    private final String content;
    private  String timestamp;
    private final String threadTs;

    global async1(String channelId, String content, String timestamp, String threadTs) {
        this.channelId = channelId;
        this.content = content;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.threadTs = threadTs;
    }

    global void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {
        try {

            
                slackThreadMessages.add(slackThreadMessage);

                insert slackThreadMessages;
            }

            System.enqueueJob(new async2(threadId, channelId, content, timestamp));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

global class async2 implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private final String threadId;
    private final String channelId;
    private final String content;
    private final String timestamp;


    global async2(String threadId, String channelId, String content, String timestamp) {
        this.threadId = threadId;
        this.channelId = channelId;
        this.content = content;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    global void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {
        try {

            // callout
            createMessageInThread(threadId, content);
            System.enqueueJob(new async3(threadId, channelId, timestamp));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

global class async3 implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private final String threadId;
    private final String channelId;
    private final String timestamp;

    global async3(String threadId, String channelId, String timestamp) {
        this.threadId = threadId;
        this.channelId = channelId;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    global void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {
        try {
            // callout
            createRunInThread(threadId);
            System.enqueueJob(new async4(threadId, channelId, timestamp));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

global class async4 implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private final String threadId;
    private final String channelId;
    private final String timestamp;

    global async4(String threadId, String channelId, String timestamp) {
        this.threadId = threadId;
        this.channelId = channelId;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    global void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {
        try {
            // callout
            String messageResponse = retrieveThreadMessages(threadId);
            
            System.enqueueJob(new async5(channelId, messageResponse, timestamp));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class async5 implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private final String channelId;
    private final String message;
    private final String timestamp;

    public async5(String channelId, String message, String timestamp){
        this.channelId = channelId;
        this.message = message;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {
        // callout
        sendSlackMessage(channelId, message, timestamp);
    }
}}

